# Syntax-highlighting comments are very picky about the number of spaces inside them

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

It seems that the comments for setting the syntax-highlighting of a code block require a space after the `language:`.

This works:

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->
```

This doesn't work:

```
<!-- language:lang-or-tag-here -->
```

A colleague of mine stumbled on this issue and we were very confused that the alternative did not work. I suspect that having a more permissive parser would not break many things, and be less confusing.

**edit**: I tested this a bit more and apparently you currently need *exactly* one space character after the `<!--`, after the `:` and before the `-->`:

Less than 1 space doesn't work:

```
 <!--language: lang-or-tag-here -->
 <!-- language:lang-or-tag-here -->
 <!-- language: lang-or-tag-here-->
```

Two or more spaces also doesn't work:

```
 <!--     language: lang-or-tag-here -->
 <!-- language:    lang-or-tag-here -->
```

You also need to use the space character (0x20). Tabs and other whitespace chars also don't work:

```
 <!--   language: lang-or-tag-here -->
```

Comment: Both in the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) as in the [What is syntax-highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/158100) there is clearly a space after the colon in all examples. Unless that can be misunderstood I don't see why the parser should allow for *syntax errors*.

Comment: Of course it can be misunderstood. I saw it happen to my colleague in front of my my own eyes.  I think the source of the confusion is that in most programming languages you don't need to have significant whitespace after non-alphabetic tokens like `:`, `,`, `+`, etc

Comment: This is definitely a usability issue. Humans can't be expected to remember all the nitty-gritty regex rules.

Comment: This is not a programming language ... and the programming languages I know are pretty strict about their syntax and if I make a mistake with that I look up the  documentation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that is how the syntax works. Should be closed as STATUS:BY DESIGN